# My function in C is not printing the value

Tags: c

i've wrote this code that is supposed to print the value of a matrix first element, but it won't work, down here is the code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
void sumer(int matrix[2])
{
    matrix[0] += 1;
    printf("%d", matrix[0]);
}
int main()
{
    int a[2];
    sumer(a[2]);

}
```

Comment: `a` is uninitialized.

Comment: `sumer(a[2]);` has to be `sumer(a);`, but you also need to initialize `a` first.

Comment: Can you describe what "doesn't work" looks like?  Asking us to guess what problem you're experiencing may not be received well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void sumer(int matrix[2]) { 
    matrix[0] += 1;
    printf("%d", matrix[0]); 
}
 int main() { 
    int a[2] = {0,0}; 
    sumer(a); 

    return 0;
}
```

You should rewrite your code like this.

Comment: `You should rewrite your code like this.` He really should not rewrite with such terrible formatting...

Comment: Yes. Thats true, im sorry because i have written this code with phone. :(

Comment: Prefer `int a[] = {0,0};`?

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. That was similar way.